# Vue multiple layout

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to follow from this question "[vuejs application with different layouts (e.g. login layout, page layout, signup etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838173/vuejs-application-with-different-layouts-e-g-login-layout-page-layout-signup)" but i cannot understand it, can anyone pls help me by giving a very simple example that I can follow in which the sample have menu as using vue-router and once i click the login button the menu will not be visible only the screen of login will be displayed.

pls help.

thank you so much

merdj

Comment: Did you already tried something yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried by following the basic of creating a project which have options of router and vuex. I was able to add child to the sample but getting rid of the menu is driving me crazy. I am trying to study the copilot sample unfortunately I cannot understand the mechanics. can anyone help me pls? thanks