# How can I use different resources for different Vue layouts?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've read related sections of the book **Full-Stack Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5** and browsed some questions (e.g. [vuejs application with different layouts (e.g. login layout, page layout, signup etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37838173/2549621)) to solve this issue. But none of them helped me.

I've created a Laravel + Vue SPA which works great. But when I want to create an administrator dashboard for this SPA with different JavaScript and CSS resources (as the dashboard should have completely different styles), I've confused too much. I don't know and understand what kind of an algorithm I should follow to do this.

You can see the general view of the software below,

```
// app.js

require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './views/App'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

// Layouts
import Default from './views/layouts/Default.vue'
import Dashboard from './views/layouts/Dashboard.vue'

Vue.component('default-layout', Default);
Vue.component('dashboard-layout', Dashboard);

Vue.config.productionTip = false

export default window.vue = new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    components: {
        App
    },
    router,
    store
});
```

```
// App.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <component :is="layout">
            <router-view/>
        </component>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';
    window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

    const default_layout = 'default';

    export default {
        name: 'App',
        computed: {
            layout() {
                return (this.$route.meta.layout || default_layout) + '-layout';
            }
        },
    };

</script>
```

```
// Default Layout

<template>
    <div>
        <default-navigation :is-absolute="isAbsolute" />
        <slot/>
        <default-footer />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import DefaultNavigation from '../components/DefaultNavigation.vue';
    import DefaultFooter from '../components/DefaultFooter.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'Default',
        components: {
            DefaultNavigation,
            DefaultFooter,
        },
        computed: {
            isAbsolute() {
                if (this.$route.name == 'home') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        },
    };

</script>
```

```
// Dashboard Layout

<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Nothing here yet. -->
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import DHeader from '../components/Dashboard/Header.vue';
    import DSidebar from '../components/Dashboard/Sidebar.vue';
    import DTitle from '../components/Dashboard/Title.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'Dashboard',
        components: {
            DHeader,
            DSidebar,
            DTitle
        },
    };

</script>
```

```
// webpack.mix.js

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/js/dashboard.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/dashboard.scss', 'public/css');
```

What should I do to use a totally different style file and an extra JavaScript file in the dashboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for separate `Vue` instances for both, then you can follow this

Create separate `blade` templates for both the instances. Add separate routes for both templates.

```
Route::get('/dashboard/{any?}', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');

Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]*');
```

Create two `Vue` instances in separate `js` files, say `app.js` and `dashboard.js`. You can create this in another directory like `dashboard/dashboard.js`

Update your `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/dashboard/dashboard.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/dashboard.scss', 'public/css');
```

You can link the build files in public to the corresponding blade templates.

Comment: In this case, should there be 2 different route.js files?

Comment: Yes, you can create two `route` files and `store` if required.

Comment: Finally, does this approach have any cons you can predict (especially regarding user authentication)?

Comment: I was using normal Laravel authentication in my application and is working perfectly.